# Create database fails with Microsoft SQL Server Error 5133, Operating syste, error 5 (Access is denied)

Tags: sql-server-2012, configuration

[image]I just installed SQL server 2012 on Windows 2012 today. After the install, I changed the database settings to create database files in f:\mssql instead of the default. i verified the confired and running values.

Create database fails to create the .mdf and .log files with the following error -
Directory lookup for the file "f:\msql\data\test.mdf' failed with os error 5. (Access is denied).

This error occurs when I run sql server service as domain account. The domain account is an administrator and has full control on volume F.

If I run the sql server service as local system, I am able to create the database with mdf files on f:\ drive.

My sysadmin confirms and I have verified that the domain account has full control on f:

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: When did you add the service account to the security group? Before or after the SQL Server install? You may just need to restart the service so that it can update its token.

Comment: Thank you Nabil. I restarted sql server service multiple times after changing the property. I did not reboot the server though. It was the os team and I believe it was after the install.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the "mssql" directory is inheriting permissions from the root of F drive?

Comment: Does the domain account have SysAdmin server role, or at least dbcreator and diskadmin?

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed. SQL Server can noow see the additional volumes besides. C:. It required applying this small changes and a server reboot. It turned out to be a VMWare HotAdd bug. Here is direct link to the VM Knowledge base article: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.dolanguage=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012225

Answer (score 0):

There is a sysinternal tool called Process Monitor (MS tool) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx that it like a "packet capture" for Windows. No need to install it, just download and run on the server. It outputs a lot of information but has great filtering capabilities.
1. Start the capture
2. Run through the process of creating the new DB until you get the error
3. Stop the capture

Then filter out everything but SQL Server process and look for Access Denied. It might give you more ideas of why you're having issues.

Comment: Hi Denis, used the tool which led me to check other things.

Comment: Cool! Is there anyway to make your attached picture bigger? I cannot see anything on it.

Comment: I seem to have hit a vmware bug. I have asked my sysadmin to check if the following is applicable. SQL Studio > Server > Properties > Database Settings > Default Locations > Browse - Does not show volume F:.                          Here is direct link to the VM Knowledge base article: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012225           I will let you know if this solution works